# rails 3 temporary user input to use for comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure how to even research this question so maybe some awesome rails developer can point me in the right direction.

I have a model that's holding a question and correct answer.  On the show view, I want the user to enter their answer into an input field and upon pressing submit, their answer is compared to the one held in the model. I don't need to save their answer.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a non ActiveRecord model for that. Something like this:

```
class UserAnswer # note that this class doesn't inherit from ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :question_id, :answer

  def initialize(params)
    @question_id = params[:question_id]
    @answer = params[:answer]
  end

  def correct?
    q = QuestionAnswerModel.find(self.question_id)
    q.answer == self.answer
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you can do something like this:

```
user_answer = UserAnswer.new(params) # params contains :question_id and :answer
user_answer.correct? # returns true or false
```

Comment: I did something sort of similar to your suggestion.  Thanks for putting me on the path!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to save the answer confirmation only if it is equal to the answer.

```
Model:
  question
  answer
  answer_confirmation
```

Then proceed to make the form as you normally would.

In the model add

```
validate :check_answer

def check_answer
  errors.add(:answer, "Must be the same as answer confirmation") if answer!= answer_confirmation
end
```

Comment: Hmm.  would this work for a has_many association?  So many users answering the model's question?

Comment: Adding has_many or user_id won't change the validator code. The validator is only interested in checking if answer is the same as the confirmation before save or create.